# PHP prints variable to screen and code stops running

Tags: php

I am trying to use [Parsedown Extra](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra) with Parsedown (Have never used either before). I have the code `$_GET` the selected category (`?cat=0`) and set it's path & filename to a var. It `$_GET`s the page number just fine, however when I set the file var, it just prints to the screen and doesn't load my page.

```
//sets the page (category) number for use with array
//also sets the path to the category's pages
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
  $catNum = $_GET['cat'];
  $catPath = 'content/' . $pageList[$catNum]['path'];

  echo '<div class="center pageNav">';

  //lists out subpages of catagory
  $pageAmt = count($pageList[$catNum]['pages']);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $pageAmt; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="' . $catPath . $pageList[$catNum]['pages'][$i]['file'] . '">' . $pageList[$catNum]['pages'][$i]['title'] . '</a>';
  };

  echo '</div>';

  //sets path & filename var to selected page: this is the part where it prints the var and doesn't run the rest. The var is pointing to the right file, I checked.
  $page = $catPath . $pageList[$catNum]['mainPage'];
} else {
  $page = 'content/home.md';
};

//parsedown
require 'parsedown/parsedown.php';
require 'parsedown/parsedownextra.php';
echo ParsedownExtra::instance()
  ->setBreaksEnabled(true)
  ->setMarkupEscaped(true)
  ->text($page);
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Parsedown takes marked up text and renders it.  In your example, you pass $page (which holds a string, a filename) to ->text($page).  This parses the string as marked up text, and renders it.  So, in your example you are seeing exactly what it is doing.  

If you are trying to run the text of the file through ->text, you need to load the file contents first and pass to Parsedown.

Comment: Oh duh. That makes sense, I totally overlooked that! Thanks :)

Comment: I posted as an answer, if it helped you, please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsedown takes marked up text and renders it. In your example, you pass $page (which holds a string, a filename) to ->text($page). This parses the string as marked up text, and renders it. So, in your example you are seeing exactly what it is doing. If you are trying to run the text of the file through ->text, you need to load the file contents first and pass to Parsedown.

Answer (score 1):

you have a semi colon at the end of your if statement.

```
} else {
  $page = 'content/home.md';
}; <--
```

Comment: Aren't I supposed to do that though? And I guess the code wasn't actually stopping at all.